# Integration by parts of covariant derivative

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, differentiation, integration, yang-mills

There already exists posts to discuss this question, but I don't think it's totally done!

We can write the covariant derivative as
$$D_i=\partial_i-igA_i^aT^a \tag{1}$$
There are two kinds of opinions about the integration by parts (IBP) of $D_i$

First opinion, $D_i$ is constructed to satisfy the Leibniz rule, see this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101982/). Like in GR, we have
$$D_i(AB)=A(D_iB)+(D_iA)B \tag{2}$$
so that
$$\int d^3 x (D_i \phi)(D_i \phi)\overset{IBP}{=}-\int d^3x \phi(D_i^2)\phi \tag{3} $$

Second opinion, only use the IBP property of $\partial_i$ inside $D_i$, like this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/611336/)
so that
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int d^3 x (D_i \phi)^\dagger(D_i \phi) \\
= &\int d^3 x (\partial_i \phi^\dagger + ig\phi^\dagger A_i^aT^a)(D_i \phi) \\
\overset{IBP}{=}&-\int d^3 x \phi^\dagger(\partial_i-igA_i^a T^a)(D_i \phi) \\
=&-\int d^3 x \phi^\dagger(D_i^2 \phi)\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

Should these two situations been satisfied simultaneously? In the second opinion, the $\dagger$ is crucial to change the sign of $i$. So these two opinions seems contradict with each other!

---

The example in opinion 1 may seems un-physical. However, I really encounter this situation in this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.2127). Let's me explain more.

Suppose we want to extract the $A_0$ component from $\int d^3 x F_{\mu\nu}^a F_{a}^{\mu \nu}$, since
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F_{a}^{\mu \nu}&=\frac{1}{2}F_{0i}^{a}F_{a}^{0i} + \frac{1}{4}F_{ij}^{a}F_{a}^{ij} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}F_{0i}^{a}F_{0i}^{a} + \frac{1}{4}F_{ij}^{a}F_{a}^{ij}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the notation in paper already turned into Euclidean time, so there doesn't has minus sign in the second line.

then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}F_{0i}^{a}F_{0i}^{a} &=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{0}A_{i}^{a}-\partial_{i}A_{0}^{a}+gf^{abc}A_{0}^{b}A_{i}^{c})(\partial_{0}A_{i}^{a}-\partial_{i}A_{0}^{a}+gf^{ade}A_{0}^{d}A_{i}^{e}) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{0}A_{i}^{a}-D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a})(\partial_{0}A_{i}^{a}-D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a}) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}[(\partial_{0}A_{i}^{a})^{2}-2(\partial_{0}A_{i}^{a})D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a}+(D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a})^{2}] \\
&\overset{*}{=}\frac{1}{2}[(D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a})^{2}] \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $D_{i}(A)=\partial_{i}-igA_{i}^{a}T^{a}$. In the step of $\overset{*}{=}$, we use the fact that gauge fields are static (in paper). Under proper representation, $T^{a}A_{0}^{b}=(\Delta^{a})^{bc}A_{0}^{c}=-if^{abc}A_{0}^{c}$. It's easy to see that

$$
\begin{aligned}
D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a}&=(\partial_{i}-igA_{i}^{b}T^{b})A_{0}^{a} \\
&=\partial_{i}A_{0}^{a}-igA_{i}^{b}(\Delta^{b})^{ac}A_{0}^{c}\\
&=\partial_{i}A_{0}^{a}-gf^{bac}A_{0}^{c} A_{i}^{b}\\
&=\partial_{i}A_{0}^{a}-gf^{acb}A_{0}^{c} A_{i}^{b} \\
&=\partial_{i}A_{0}^{a}-gf^{abc}A_{0}^{b} A_{i}^{c} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So at last, we can write
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int d^3 x \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^a F_{a}^{\mu \nu}\\
 &=\int d^3 x \bigg[\frac{1}{2}[D_{i}(A) A_{0}^{a}]^{2} +\frac{1}{4}F_{ij}^{a}F_{ij}^{a}\bigg]  
\end{aligned}
$$
while in the paper that I mentioned (the equation above (10) in paper), the final form is
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int d^3 x \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^a F_{a}^{\mu \nu}\\
&=\int d^3 x \bigg[-\frac{1}{2}A_{0}^{a}[D_{i}(A)D_{i}(A)] A_{0}^{a}   + \frac{1}{4}F_{ij}^{a}F_{ij}^{a}\bigg]
\end{aligned}
$$
that's where I encountered this situation of opinion 1.

Comment: Why are you taking the integrand in (2) as being of the form $X_iX_i$ instead of $X_i^\dagger X_i$?

Comment: @J.G. To fit the property of Leibniz rule. Otherwise, it's not clear to me if $D_i(A^\dagger B)=A^\dagger (D_i B)+ (D_i A)^\dagger B$ is true?

Comment: What I mean is, do you understand the physics concerning which of $\int d^3x(D_i\phi)(D_i\phi),\,\int d^3x(D_i\phi)^\dagger(D_i\phi)$ is more relevant in e.g. Lagrangians?

Comment: @J.G.  Thanks! Yes, $\int d^3 x (D_i \phi)^\dagger (D_i \phi)$
is more relevant in Lagrangians. But I really encountered term like $\int d^3x (D_i A_0)(D_i A_0)$
 in the small fluctuation expansion of $F_{\mu\nu} F_{\mu \nu}$
term in published papers. They finally reach a term like $-\int d^3x A_0(D_i^2A_0)$, where $A_0$ is the zero component of the gauge potential. In this paper journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.2127, above equation (10).

Comment: Unfortunately I lack access to that paper, so you might want to edit an excerpt of it into your question for context.

Comment: @J.G. Sure, I’ll edit in a few hours today, then I’ll let you know, thanks!

Comment: @J.G. I update the post! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @J.G. you can see that paper here: https://lib-extopc.kek.jp/preprints/PDF/1990/9005/9005224.pdf

Comment: @Baela Thank you; I still have much to learn about finding PDFs. I note the paper only lacks the ${}^\dagger$ on $D_iA$, not $D_i\phi$, which is crucial because classically $A$ is real while $\phi$ is complex.

Comment: @J.G. You're welcome. I found the above link by visiting the Inspire HEP webpage of the paper: https://inspirehep.net/literature/295436
There you see the text "View in:" next to which there are three links. The third one has free access.